# Is it possible to add a parameter in an IF condition?

Tags: php, if-statement

I'd like to display data from tables. Some user may have only certain data. I have this parameter:

```
if($person == "nonmember"){
    $st_show = ' == 3'; //For non member show rows with status of 3
}else{
    $st_show = ' <> 3'; //For member show rows with status of not 3. Status may dynamically increased and changed
}
```

How can I loop the rows based on the parameter above. Something like this :

```
if($rows->STATUS echo $st_show){
    //show data based on $person
}
```

I know it returns an error. Are there any solutions for me beside than do these limitation in database?

Comment: Select rows from database using required condition.

Comment: @u_mulder I'm looking for PHP only solutions

Comment: it seems like you want to make a condition on the SQL, and not in PHP

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like...

```
if(($person == "nonmember" && $status == 3) || 
          ($person == "member" && $status <> 3)){
   // Show record
}
```

Comment: This works very nice. Thank you